# Failed to open the bootstrap file in MySQL

Tags: rhel, mysql, oracle-linux

After doing an installation of MySQL Ver. 5.7.10 for RH/Oracle Linux I get an error that during the initialization the bootstrap file was not found. I'm not sure where this may come from, as it is a fresh installation and the error was not yet covered.

The rights to the folder were set up correctly by the installer:

```
# ls -l /var/lib | grep mysql-files
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql         mysql         4096 Dec  8 15:13 mysql-files
```

`mysqld.log`:

```
2015-12-08T14:13:24.524728Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-12-08T14:13:26.107212Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2015-12-08T14:13:26.440941Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2015-12-08T14:13:26.612704Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: d95e041f-9db5-11e5-a33f-525400eb9be6.
2015-12-08T14:13:26.650484Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2015-12-08T14:13:26.668489Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: YZ+#zIY/m2=:
2015-12-08T14:13:39.994706Z 1 [ERROR] Failed to open the bootstrap file /var/lib/mysql-files/install-validate-password-plugin.OFJRaf.sql
2015-12-08T14:13:39.994728Z 1 [ERROR] 1105  Bootstrap file error, return code (0). Nearest query: 'LSE SET @sys.tmp.table_exists.SQL = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `', in_db, '`.`', in_table, '`'); PREPARE stmt_select FROM @sys.tmp.table_exists.SQL; IF (NOT v_error) THEN DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_select; SET out_exists = 'TEMPORARY'; END IF; END IF; END;
'
2015-12-08T14:13:39.994880Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error installing mysql-community-server from Oracle repo.

Solved by running `mysqld_safe` with statements to reset password. Quite weird right?

`/tmp/mysql-init.txt`:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('p@ssw0rd')
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Start `mysqld_safe`:

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/tmp/mysql-init.txt
```

Make sure new password already set:

```
service mysqld stop
service mysqld start
chkconfig mysqld on
```

Test root's password with mysql CLI:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: You just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug related with SELinux, you can check details [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79458)

You can use follow these steps:

Step1: disable SELinux by using the command below:

```
setenforce 0
```

Step2: Start mysql service as follows:

```
service mysqld start
```

Now it should be fine.

Step3: Change root password (also secure it) using the command:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Provide pass provided by mysql (check in mysqld.log), and create new password.

Step4: Enable SELinux feature again using the command:

```
setenforce 1
```

Note that if you stop/restart/start mysql service, then no need to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error: mysql cannot access bootstrap file even it has read permission (`chmod 644`).

The solution was to `chown` this bootstrap file to mysql:

```
# chown mysql:mysql /tmp/mysql-init-file.sql
```